# How to filter out a list by majority in python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a algorithm where it takes value from a ultrasonic sensor(distance sensor) which is constantly reading and calculating the average of the last 10 taken value. The problem is with the ultrasonic sensor will have random spikes which will significantly throw off the average reading

```
example of readings

19.42
19.43
130.50
19.46
19.44
19.42
144.52
19.4
145.90
19.37
[Average Distance:23] #just a example not actual results
```

so now I am wondering if there is any method to disregard the high value base on majority, say if the list has a majority of small values it will ignore the high value and vice versa, if there are majority of high values ignore small values.

```
example of desired result

19.42
19.43
130.50  
19.46
19.44
19.42
144.52
19.4
145.90
19.37
[Average Distance:19]  #ignored spiked values are the majority of numbers are 19
```

Do let me know if Further explanation/examples are needed, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are looking for what is called a robust statistic like the `median`.

Comment: @cbo , Ah thank you after googling that it does seem like it is what I need, I will update the tread If I get the code working thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `numpy.median`:

```
import numpy as np
vals = np.array([19.42
,19.43
,130.50  
,19.46
,19.44
,19.42
,144.52
,19.4
,145.90
,19.37])
np.median(vals)
```

produces 19.435. Median is a point such that half the observations are above and half are below, see [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)